# Modifying content of Wordpress RSS Feed

Tags: php, wordpress, rss

I am trying to move the custom field `<rule_short_summary>` into the field `<content:encoded>` so I may display it in an automated newsletter.

This is what I have:

```php
function my_add_to_content($content) {
  $post_id = get_the_ID();
  $rule_short_summary = get_the_terms($post_ID, 'rule_short_summary');
    return  $rule_short_summary;
}
add_filter('the_content_feed', 'my_add_to_content');
```

Currently content:encoded returns an empty field.

I am taking inspiration from this link:
http://https//digwp.com/2019/09/add-content-wordpress-feed/
In this link, the author adds custom text to the content. I want to pull from another field and add to the content.

Comment: is `rule_short_summary` a "custom field" or a "term"?

Answer (score 0):

Custom fields can be called using get_post_meta function.
In your given code you have use get_the_terms function - which is wrong for this case of course.

```
function my_add_to_content($content) {
  $post_id = get_the_ID();
  $rule_short_summary = get_post_meta($post_ID, 'rule_short_summary',true);
    return  $rule_short_summary;
}
add_filter('the_content_feed', 'my_add_to_content');
```